# Select multiple items in a listview

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a listview which is connected to a cursor adapter. The user should be able to select multiple items from the listview and delete them when the user clicks a button below the listview. Actionbar is not involved in the app. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the

```
    android:choiceMode
```

attribute. You can set it to

```
multipleChoice
multipleChoiceModal
none
singleChoice
```

Comment: What i want is to is to implement a listener which listens for different items selected, so that i can act on them.

Answer (score 0):

can you please look at below blogs : 
1. http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-create-multi-select-listview-android-with-custom-adapter/ 
2. http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/10/multi-selection-listview-example-in.html